# Ignoring String value while importing from Excel in R

Tags: r, dataframe, export

I have a Excel file "inputdataParameters.xlsx"  with a worksheet called "parameters", here is an example of the input data from the file.

```
Code             Value                    Description
SUP_UMBRAL        13                    Superior Umbral
INF_UMBRAL        5                     Inferior Umbral
ROUTE     C:/Desktop/OutPut/            Route to save the output
```

Here is my code for getting the value from the excel Worksheet called "parameters".

```
canal_input_parameters <- odbcConnectExcel2007("inputdataParameters.xlsx", readOnly = TRUE)

parameters <- sqlFetch(canal_input_parameters, "parameters ")
```

My problem is that, when I export it to create a dataframe, the numeric values are correctly appearing, but ROUTE that has to be a string or similar format is appearing on my dataframe as "NA" value.

OutPut dataframe example;

```
     Code             Value                    Description
    SUP_UMBRAL        13                    Superior Umbral
    INF_UMBRAL        5                     Inferior Umbral
    ROUTE             NA          Route to save the output
```

Comment: A column of a data frame can only have one data type. So you probably need to have values 13,5 as strings and not numbers.

Comment: Note that there are now much easier and direct ways than `RODBC` to import data from Excel. You might want to consider `readxl` (very straightforward and good for importing) or `openxlsx` (for import or export but can be a little more complicated.)